# Data Structure for an array of Dictionary entries

Tags: java

I am looking for a native way (preferably) in java to implement a data structure to hold an int as key and a set of key/value pair as the value. In essence if would be an array of dictionaires referenced by an index.

Ex:

```
MyDataStructure[[Key,Value]] foo = new ...

foo.put[["hello", "world"], ["so","rocks"]]
```

`println(foo[0].getValue("hello"))` would print out `"world"` and `println(foo[0].getValue("so"))` would print out `"rocks"`

Comment: Consider a Map<Integer,Pair<String,String>>. Pair is just a simple java class. It will be much more efficient than using an entire Map to store a simple name, value pair...

Comment: So i just implement the pair class myself correct? with just one constructor and two fields? And that would be more efficient than the solutions such as Map<Key,Value>?

Comment: Im kinda surprised there is no simple way to just create an array that holds a dictionary. I am coming from Objective-C and it was simple to do so there

Comment: Yes it will be. Pair is just a suggestion use a meaning full name with meaning full fields. Oh you can of course always use an array of two elements. But that seems rather ugly when much more nice provisions exist don't you think? And why do you want to access the elements with their index? If you can eliminate that you will be able to use a Map without any customization.

Comment: I want to access the elements by their index because they hold key/value type information such as key:name value:john. i wanted to avoid creating objects out of all of these and just have a collection of key/value pairs to represent an object to save on memory. Do you think that is wise? I should add that this is for an android project

Comment: A simple object like Pair will not have a performance impact. So I wouldn't worry about that even in android. Yes but if you want to simply get a value for a particular key what use is the index? Making you code complex for an perceived performance gain is hardly wise so I'd suggest that you go with this approach unless you profile the code and find this is where the performance hit is at (highly unlikely).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30801/discussion-between-john-baum-and-thihara)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- If you know in advance number of dictionaries, then minimum structure is array of Map:

  ```
  Map<Key,Value>[] dictonaires = new HashMap<Key,Value>[20];
  for (int i=0; i<dictionaries.length; i++) {
      dictionaries[i] = new Hashmap<Key,Value>();
  }

  // Any time later, refer to a dictionary by index 
  Map<Key,Value> currentDictionary = dictionaries[10];
  // Can call currentDictionar.put/get/remove to create or update/read/delete 
  // entries, but can't add/remove entire dictionaries
  ```
- But a more flexible structure is `List<Map<Key,Value>>`, because number of dictionaries can change dynamically.  Any `List` will work - but in your case, `ArrayList` would be best for fast access (get) by index:

  ```
  List<Map<Key,Value>> dictionaryList = new ArrayList<Map<Key,Value>>();

  // Then add new dictionary anytime later:
  dictionaryList.add(new HashMap<Key,Value>());    

  // Access by index (index matches order of adding):
  Map<Key,Value> currentDictionary = dictionaryList.get(10);    
  // Can call currentDictionar.put/get/remove to create or update/read/delete 
  // entries, but can't add/remove entire dictionaries

  // Or even remove entire dictionary by index:
  dictionaryList.remove(10);
  ```

Answer (score 2):

How about a Map

```
Map<Integer, Map<Key, Value>> myMap;
```

A concrete implementation is the `HashMap`

Comment: How efficient would this be?

Comment: @JohnBaum evaluating this proposal is part of your work, not from Mekswoll.

Answer (score 0):

Here take a look at HashMaps

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

I think that is what you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

The map interface is what you are looking for it seems, a specific implementation:

```
    Map<Integer, Map<String, String>> map = new HashMap<>();
    Map<String, String> someInsert = new HashMap<>();
    someInsert.put("No", "Means no");
    map.put(0, someInsert);

    System.out.println(map.get(0).get("No"));
```

Out:

```
Means no
```